# How to make batch file to open specific Profiles in Google Chrome

Tags: windows, google-chrome, batch-file, user-profiles

I have `.BAT` batch files to open a set of programs, web pages and explorer windows. With sufficient Googling I've still come up short as how to execute the profile target

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Profile 1"
```

by batch. A workaround would be to run that link by batch, but I would feel more comfortable knowing the computer has one less step to achieve the same goal.

I feel I'm close to an easy fix here, but don't have the batch command line knowledge resources nor terminology to search adequately I'm afraid.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what the question is? You don't explain what is not working. Why is 1 more command an issue?

Comment: Essentially just searching for the command line to run a shortcut from a batch file. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

#### How can I run Chrome with a specified profile in a batch file?

Use `start`:

```
start "Chrome" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Profile 1"
```

---

> **Syntax**
>
> `START "title" [/D path] [options] "command" [parameters]`

Source [Start a program, command or batch script (opens in a new window.)](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [start](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) - Start a program, command or batch script (opens in a new window).

Answer (score 0):

start "Chrome" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Profile 2"

start "webpage name" "http://someurl.com/"

start "Chrome" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --profile-directory="Profile 3"

start "webpage name" "http://someurl.com/"

Comment: How is this different than the answer by @DavidPostill? Can you elaborate?